# Google Apps Script - Google Document : Find headings attributes

Tags: google-apps-script, styles, google-docs

I'm trying to read a google document to find style attributes. For example, get a paragraph with the heading "Heading 1", and then get the style attributes. But all attributes are 'null'. I don't know where to find information about (headings attributes) using GAS.

Comment: So, you are using code that is something like the code in Google's documentation at this link?  [Google Documentation - getAttributes Header](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section#getAttributes())

Answer (score 1):

These are all the attributes listed in the code editor auto-complete help:

```
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.CODE
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.GLYPH_TYPE
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_END
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_FIRST_LINE
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_START
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LEFT_TO_RIGHT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINK_URL
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LIST_ID
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_BOTTOM
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_LEFT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_RIGHT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_TOP
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.MINIMUM_HEIGHT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.NESTING_LEVEL
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_LEFT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_RIGHT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_TOP
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PAGE_HEIGHT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.PAGE_WIDTH
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.STRIKETHROUGH
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.WIDTH
```